# Extract Property value from NodeList

Tags: javascript

Inside a javascript function Im accessing a text box with a value of 'c29TMlzE4vmFlJHieICpso_u04oa'. Below is the javascript function i'm using.

```
 function test(){
        var txt = document.getElementsByName("consumerKey");
        alert(txt.item[0].getPropertyValue);
    }
```

The alert shows as 'undefined'. In console I'm getting below as NodeList value of the txt.

```
NodeList[input#consumerKey property value ="c29TMlzE4vmFlJHieICpso_u04oa"  attribute value = "null"]
```

How can I extract 'c29TMlzE4vmFlJHieICpso_u04oa' from the nodelist.

Thanks

Comment: try `text.item(0).value`. `item` is a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` is a method, so you call it with a parameter:

```
txt.item(0)
```

Or you could access it as

```
txt[0]
```

`getPropertyValue` is for getting CSS property values from a style object, and is not relevant here. You simply want to access the `value` member of the input element:

```
txt.item(0).value
txt[0].value
```

However, there is really no need to use name attributes, except in special situations such as to group radio buttons. You're better off using IDs and `getElementById`. Then you don't have to worry about taking the first item.